# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'app-ques-navbar' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on putting together a multi-step form. I am using the instructions here as an instruction guide:

https://www.cc28tech.com/angular-multi-step-wizard-part-1/

I am working with Angular 5.

As of now, I am doing a test whereby the main HTML component `admin-reg-ques` calls a sub-ordinate HTML component `ques-navbar`.

When I type: `http://localhost:4200/admin/admin-reg-ques`

I get the following error:

```
VM6056 core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-ques-navbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-ques-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-ques-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <div style="background:white">
      <h1>stuff is in here</h1>
      [ERROR ->]<app-ques-navbar></app-ques-navbar>
  </div>
</body>"): ng:///AuthAdminModule/AdminRegQuesComponent.html@3:6
Error: Template parse errors:
'app-ques-navbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-ques-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-ques-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <div style="background:white">
      <h1>stuff is in here</h1>
      [ERROR ->]<app-ques-navbar></app-ques-navbar>
  </div>
</body>"): ng:///AuthAdminModule/AdminRegQuesComponent.html@3:6
```

The file structure is as like the picture below:

[image]

**QUESTIOBN: What am I doing wrong?**

**ques-navbar.component.html**

```
<h1>navigation bar goes here </h1>
```

**ques-navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ques-navbar',
  templateUrl: './ques-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ques-navbar.component.css']
})
export class QuesNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  // need for work with the Template = do not erase!
  ngAfterViewInit() { document.getElementById('preloader').classList.add('hide'); }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }    
}
```

**admin-reg-ques.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-reg-ques',
  templateUrl: './admin-reg-ques.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-reg-ques.component.css']
})
export class AdminRegQuesComponent implements OnInit {

  // need for work with the Template = do not erase!
  ngAfterViewInit() { document.getElementById('preloader').classList.add('hide'); }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**admin-reg-ques.component.html**

```
<body style="background-color: white">
  <div style="background:white">
      <h1>item is in here</h1>
      <app-ques-navbar></app-ques-navbar>
  </div>
</body>
```

**SPECIAL NOTE**

If I change **admin-reg-ques.component.html** to the following, I do not get the error:

```
<body style="background-color: white">
  <div style="background:white">
      <h1>item is in here</h1>
      <!-- <app-ques-navbar></app-ques-navbar> -->
  </div>
</body>
```

**admin-reg-ques.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { QuesMainComponent } from './ques-main/ques-main.component';
import { QuesDoneComponent } from './ques-done/ques-done.component';
import { QuesAddressComponent } from './ques-address/ques-address.component';
import { QuesNavbarComponent } from './ques-navbar/ques-navbar.component';
import { QuesWorkflowComponent } from './ques-workflow/ques-workflow.component';
import { AdminRegQuesComponent } from './admin-reg-ques.component';

export const routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo:'admin-reg-ques', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'admin-reg-ques', component: AdminRegQuesComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [QuesMainComponent, QuesDoneComponent, QuesAddressComponent, QuesNavbarComponent, QuesWorkflowComponent]
})
export class AdminRegQuesModule { }
```

Comment: Probably miss to add QuesNavbarComponent in declaration array of your module ?

Comment: @Gilsdav - thanks for the response. I have added **admin-reg-ques.module.ts** to the message above. Can you note where I am to make the change? TIA

Comment: It look's like you are using AdminRegQuesComponent into an other module because : "routes" is not used here and AdminRegQuesComponent is not declared here. Please put everything of same feature in same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the module `AdminRegQuesModule` is being imported by another module that needs to make your `QuesNavbarComponent` rendered then you need to export it in your `AdminReqQuesModule`.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
       CommonModule
   ],
   declarations: [QuesMainComponent, QuesDoneComponent, QuesAddressComponent, QuesNavbarComponent, QuesWorkflowComponent],
   exports: [QuesMainComponent, QuesDoneComponent, QuesAddressComponent, QuesNavbarComponent, QuesWorkflowComponent]
})
export class AdminRegQuesModule { }
```

This should make your components visible in other modules.

As you can see from the error, there is a reference to `AuthAdminModule`. Are you trying to inject the components within this module?

Comment: Technicaly correct but do not respect "Feature module" guidelines.

Comment: @Gilsdav I am not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic The folder structure explicitly say that QuesNavbarComponent will only be used in AdminRegQuesModule (especially in AdminRegQuesComponent).
The problem is the wrong usage of modules.

Comment: Are you saying that his `AdminReqQuesModule` should not export all the features but rather one major component that internally hosts all other components? You are right about that, but technically this was more of an answer that provides a solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes, export a major component or export nothing because this Module have routes so it can be totaly independent. But for sure your quick fix will works.